How can I save to OneDrive or Google Drive with React Native?
I have created a React Native application. This application allows the user to input information. All of the information entered by the user is saved to a JSON file.
How can I allow the user to save this information to their personal OneDrive or Google Drive as a backup?
Looking online, I have found multiple articles and videos on how to save data to a single OneDrive account using Azure Active Directory and Google Cloud. However, I don't want to save this JSON file to a server, that I have access to. Instead, I want to allow the user to save the JSON file to their own personal OneDrive or Google Drive.

I haven't tagged the question
I have attempted to find code to do this. However, I haven't found any. The code isn't something I can attempt to write
